# Bitbucket carriage return

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I push my source back to Bitbucket, I find BB cannot find the places I modified. I just input several carriage return problem in somewhere of the code but BB treat it as a big change of whole file and mark the whole file red or green. Any solution to this?

Comment: Are you using git or mercurial? And what platform are you running on? My first thought is it's a file-encoding issue at your end - converting CR/LF to LF (or not).

Comment: As of the end of January 2015, bitbucket **[now provides](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/01/30/new-year-new-features/ "ignoring whitespace in diffs plus other goodies")** the feature that Simon mentions below. For bitbucket, it looks like you tack `?w=1` onto the end of the url when viewing a commit and it will show you the whitespace-ignorant changes.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a line-ending issue.

Windows and UNIX system don't use same line-ending, to prevent conflict from happening based on these, you should setup you git config this way:

- on Windows : `git config --global core.autocrlf true`
- on Unix : `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

The idea is to always push LF (Unix style). This way, Bitbucket or Git won't mark all line ending as changed resulting in huge diff file.

A side note, on Github, you can add `?w=0` to the end of URL to see the diff by ignoring whitespace. I don't know any similar feature on bitbucket unfortunatly :(

Comment: This is now available on Bitbucket via `?w=1`. See comment on question.

Comment: @Simon Boudrias, How can I make sure that I push only `LF` from my windows machine? I'm using `core.autocrlf true`. Thanks.